# Android: How to get the value like 04 instead of the 4 during parsing string to Integer?

Tags: java, string, time, numbers, integer

I am storing the String value to the integer.

```
String a="04";
int aInt = Integer.parseInt(a) ;
```

but then I get 4 instead of the 04.

So what should i have to do for it ?
Thanks.

Comment: more of a core Java question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you need 04 in a int variable as there will be no meaning of it. ya but when you want to print it it may be your requirement to display leading zeros.

adding leading 0 in an integer doesn't make any sense internally. so better you can handle tis part when you want to display.

you can display leading zeros as follow:

```
 String stringToDisplay = String.format("%02d", aInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str;
    if(aInt < 10) {
    str  = "0"+aInt;
    }
```

Try it out

Comment: @Richa You are right but it is again become String.He needs int value if i m not wrong?

Comment: @AndroidKiller : you can also add 0 before actual number.

Comment: @Richa if you are writing 04 it's ok.But there is single 4 then how u can add 0 to it programmatically as needed in question?